# Samsung Smart TV UA43N5300ARLXL/UA43N5300ARXXL unable to connect to internet over UFW firewall

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, tcp

I have a home network with a Raspberry Pi at the center running Pihole and UFW. The Pihole is both the DHCP as well as DNS server.

Ever since I started using Pi Hole I've not had any issues until recently when I turned on UFW.

My Samsung Smart TV (UA43N5300ARLXL/UA43N5300ARXXL) would neither acquire IP address using DHCP and even if I use manual IP and then try, it doesn't go through. But if I switch off UFW, it works like a charm. I checked the UFW Audit logs but nothing very obvious.

Here's the summary of the rules I've setup in UFW:

Allowed ports:

To                         Action      From

---

1725/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

5353                       ALLOW      21.30.0.0/16

80                         ALLOW      21.30.0.0/16

53                         ALLOW      21.30.0.0/16

67                         ALLOW      21.30.0.0/16

68                         ALLOW      21.30.0.0/16

22                         ALLOW      21.30.0.0/16

80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere

4711                       ALLOW      21.30.0.0/16

10000                      ALLOW      21.30.0.0/16

2501                       ALLOW      21.30.0.0/16

53/udp on eth0             ALLOW       Anywhere

80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       Anywhere

123/udp                    ALLOW      21.30.0.0/16

1725/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

53/udp (v6) on eth0        ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

80,443/tcp (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Would appreciate any help in understanding how Samsung Smart TVs handle network connections and the ports they use as well as any input to fine tune UFW to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the ufw rule for DHCP helped-

ufw allow proto udp from 0.0.0.0/0 to 0.0.0.0/0 port 67

This allows the initial DHCP check by a new device broadcasting from 0.0.0.0